# React-Native-Firebase : RTDB Emulator

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, react-native-firebase, firebase-tools

Does anybody knows how to use realtime database emulators?

I can use function & firestore emulators like below.

```
import functions from '@react-native-firebase/functions';
import firestore from '@react-native-firebase/firestore';

functions().useFunctionsEmulator('http://localhost:5001');
firestore().settings({ host: 'localhost:8080' });
```

But was not able to find something similar for realtime database.
Any link/video is appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the documentation on [Connect your app to the Realtime Database Emulator](https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite/connect_rtdb#web), that is done with:

```
if (location.hostname === "localhost") {

  var firebaseConfig = {
    // Point to the RTDB emulator running on localhost.
    // In almost all cases the ns (namespace) is your project ID.
    databaseURL: "http://localhost:9000?ns=YOUR_DATABASE_NAMESPACE"
  }

  var myApp = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  var db = myApp.database();
}
```

---

I'm not certain if that is supported in `react-native-firebase` yet, since it isn't mentioned in their documentation at all. The most logical things to try would be their [Using a secondary database](https://rnfirebase.io/database/usage#using-a-secondary-database):

```
const database = firebase.app().database('http://localhost:9000?ns=YOUR_DATABASE_NAMESPACE');
```

Comment: But using RNFirebase, I don't need to do any `initializaApp`

Comment: Yeah, it look they don't have native methods for that. You might want to try what I just added.

Comment: Thanks, Frank. That looks reasonable to me, and I will try that.

Comment: Did that work? API wise it seems like the call should work, but I'm curious if it then calls into the emulator.

Answer (score 4):

Basically the solution posted by [Frank van Puffelen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/209103/frank-van-puffelen) was correct. However, this got me stuck for a while so I'm going to share my experience to save time for others.

```
import { firebase } from "@react-native-firebase/database";
const database = firebase
  .app()
  .database("http://localhost:9000?ns=YOUR_DATABASE_NAMESPACE");
const ref = database.ref(`yourPath`)
...
```

Here comes the huge gotcha:
If you're using Android Emulator you have to use

```
const database = firebase
  .app()
  .database("http://10.0.2.2:9000?ns=YOUR_DATABASE_NAMESPACE");
```

If you're using a real android device you have to set up [reverse proxy](https://handstandsam.com/2016/02/01/network-calls-from-android-device-to-laptop-over-usb-via-adb/) first:

```
adb reverse tcp:9000 tcp:9000
```

then set up the database normally

```
const database = firebase
  .app()
  .database("http://localhost:9000?ns=YOUR_DATABASE_NAMESPACE");
```

I didn't test for iOS, but I believe localhost should work.

Answer (score 1):

I have this in my root index.js file for my react native project:

```
// Use a local emulator in development
if (__DEV__) {
  // If you are running on a physical device, replace http://localhost with the local ip of your PC. (http://192.168.x.x)
  auth().useEmulator('http://localhost:9099');
  functions().useFunctionsEmulator('http://localhost:5001');
  database().useEmulator('localhost', 9000);

  const db = firestore();
  db.settings({ host: 'localhost:8080', ssl: false });
}
```

Nothing else in my app needed to be modified.  The `database().useEmulator` line does the trick.

I am assuming you have already initialized all the emulators first using `firebase init emulators` and have them running with `firebase emulators:start`.

Make sure you're using the `${projectId}-default-rtdb` database in the emulator.